# Is Dragon Quest 11 Switch playable with only 1 Joycon?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

As the title says, I'd like to know if it's possible to play DQ11 single handedly (or at least do most of the stuff with one joycon, left or right).

Some of the older DQ allows to Confirm/Cancel with the trigger button, making it somewhat playable one handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, someone caved in and bought me the game.

Unfortunately, I can't say that you can play one handed.
There's a lot of stuff you can't do with only one hand (most notable, cancelling, opening the menu, sprinting).